# Find Number of Observations (N) for a praise.winsten time-series regression in R

Tags: r, time-series, regression, panel-data

I am using the praise.winsten package to run some panel time-series regression analysis in R and need a command function to tell me the number of observations in my model.

The base R command, 'nobs()', that I normally use for basic linear regression, 'lm()', doesn't seem to work for this.

Does anyone have any ideas?

I tried the 'nobs()' command, but that doesn't work for the prais package apparently

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with any code you've tried so far and your data (or an example dataset)?

Comment: Sure... here is the code that I am using ---- mod1 <- prais_winsten(gini ~ edex, data = testdata, index = "year")
summary(mod1) #total edu exp & dependent gini

Comment: Can you use `dput(testdata)` to provide your dataset? You can post the output from `dput()` as well as your model code in your original question as an edit.